# Interface with generic parameter vs Interface with generic methods

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Let's say I have such interface and concrete implementation

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T My();
}

public class MyConcrete : IMyInterface<string>
{
    public string My()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

So I create MyConcrete implementation for `strings`, I can have one more concrete implementation for `int`. And that's ok. But let's say, that I want to do the same thing, but with generic methods, so I have

```
public interface IMyInterface2
{
    T My<T>();
}

public class MyConcrete2 : IMyInterface2
{
    public string My<string>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So I have the same `IMyInterface2`, but which defines generic behavior by means of `T My<T>()`. In my concrete class I want to implement `My` behavior, but for concrete data type - `string`. But C# doesn't allow me to do that.

My question is why I cannot do that?
In other words, if i can create concrete implementation of `MyInterface<T>` as `MyClass : MyInterface<string>` and stop genericness at this point, why I can't do that with generic method - `T My<T>()`?

Comment: You cannot *reduce* abilities when inheriting types, you can only add to them.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your generic method implementation has to be generic as well, so it has to be:

```
public class MyConcrete2 : IMyInterface2
{
    public T My<T>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Why you can't do `My<string>()` here? Because interface contract needs a method, that could be called with any type parameter `T` and you have to fulfill that contract.

**Why you can't *stop genericness in this point*?** Because it would cause situations like following:

*Class declarations:*

```
public interface IMyInterface2
{
    T My<T>(T value);
}

public class MyClass21 : IMyInterface2
{
    public string My<string>(string value) { return value; }
}

public class MyClass22 : IMyInterface2
{
    public int My<int>(int value) { return value; }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var item1 = new MyClass21();
var item2 = new MyClass22();

// they both implement IMyInterface2, so we can put them into list
var list = new List<IMyInterface2>();
list.Add(item1);
list.Add(item2);

// iterate the list and call My method
foreach(IMyInterface2 item in list)
{
    // item is IMyInterface2, so we have My<T>() method. Choose T to be int and call with value 2:
    item.My<int>(2);

    // how would it work with item1, which has My<string> implemented?
}
```

Comment: It needs to be public `T My<T>()`

Comment: if i can create concrete implementation of MyInterface<T> as MyClass : MyInterface<string> and stop genericness in this point, why I can't do that with generic method - T My<T>()?

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov Check my update. I showed a situation when your `My<string>` implementation would fail.

Comment: agree. but in fact it can use actual type in this case and call concrete implementation using polymorphic behavior of the object.

Comment: How would you like to do that?

Comment: Explicit specialization of generic methods not supported in C#

Answer (score 5):

Because your interface declares a generic method `T My<T>()`, but you implementation does not implement a function with that specific signature.

To achieve what you want, you need to provide the T generic parameter to the interface instead, in your first example:

```
public interface IMyInterface2<T>
{
        T My();
}

public class MyConcrete2 : IMyInterface2<string>
{
    public string My()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to achieve what I want, I want to know why I cannot stop genericness as I can do with the interfaces

Answer (score 3):

when you write the Generic Method the Definition is for keeping the placeholder. Actual Type comes into picture when you call the method. so instead you should write

```
public T My<T>()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and when you call the method you can use the string there.

Comment: I want to stop generecness as I can do with generic interface, e.g. MyClass : MyInterface<string>

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not work for two reasons.

First, an interface is a contract.  When you implement `IMyInterface2` you guarantee that you will implement a function named `My` that takes a generic type parameter and returns that type.  `MyConcrete2` does not do this.

Second, C# generics do not allow any kind of type parameter specialization. (I do wish C# supported this.)  This is a common thing in C++ templates where your example would compile, but any usages of `MyConcrete2` would fail to compile if they don't call `My` with a `string`.